# How to change the android launcher icon for xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

There are 2 places I can change the icon for my xamarin forms android project.
One is in the 
.Android > MainActivity.cs

```
  [Activity(Label = "ZammyTestApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

and there is also the manifest file. 
Which one is the right place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will suggest you to change the icon from MainActivity. Suppose you have an icon activity definition in your MainActivity and then you try to change icon from manifest file, icon would not change because **icon activity definition in your Main Activity overrides the manifest.**

**Why MainActivity overrides the manifest?**

If you click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest#the-basics), document states that **if you use `[Activity]` custom attribute, it causes xml fragment to be added to AndroidManifest.xml at compile time.**

Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest#activity-icon) to see that how the `[Activity]` attribute helps to produce icon in xml fragment. **For example:**

```
[Activity (Label="My App", MainLauncher=true, Icon="@drawable/myicon")] 
public class MyActivity : Activity 
{
}
```

This example produces the following xml fragment:

```
<activity android:icon="@drawable/myicon" android:label="My App" 
      android:name="md5a7a3c803e481ad8926683588c7e9031b.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And check the accepted answer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59546/cannot-change-icon-from-default-xamarin-icon) in xamarin forums.

Comment: thank you sir. From my experince i did find that icon activity definition in my main acitivty overrid the manifest . Where can i find refrence stating this though?